# Class[] - What does it mean?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm looking at a tutorial found on: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0603/

In particular there is a section where it gives the following example:

```
Class[] types = new Class[] { String.class, String.class };
Constructor cons = TwoString.class.getConstructor(types);
Object[] args = new Object[] { "a", "b" };
TwoString ts = (TwoString)cons.newInstance(args);
```

I don't quite follow what Class[] represents.  The way I read it, this says 'an array of Class objects called types].  I'm also somewhat unfamiliar with the syntax used in the new statements - how does new Class[] { String.class, String.class} work?

If someone can help break this down for me I would appreciate it.

Comment: See [Array Types: Java in a Nutshell](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_09.htm) -- the "array literals" section in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the literal meaning is exactly what you are thinking it is

`Class[] types = new Class[] { String.class, String.class };` is a declaration and initialization in one line. It says create an array that holds objects of type `Class` and initialize it with two objects of type `Class`, namely String.class and String.class.

A similar example would be

```
int[] nums = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

or

```
float[] decimals = new float[]{1.2, 3.1, 5.2}
```

Comment: Cool, I haven't seen this syntax before.  It was my understanding you could just say Int[] nums = {1,2,3}; and skip the new statement.

Comment: yup. the syntax is a little redundant when you are using initialization like this. I don't the internals well enough but maybe there is a reason why they don't just do it without the `new Class[]` part

Comment: The `new type[]{...}` syntax works also when the variable is not declared in the same statement, though.

Answer (score 2):

A `Class` is an `Object` that describes a java class (or interface). A `Class[]` is an array of these objects.

The syntax `<ClassName>.class` (e.g. `String.class`) returns the `Class` for a particular java class (or interface).

A new array can be created through a few syntax. `new Class[i]` creates a new array of `Class` with length `i` and filled with default values (null references).  `new Class[]{a, b, c}` creates a new array of `Class` containing the given elements `a`, `b` and `c`. It's length is 3 because 3 elements were given.

Answer (score 1):

It is an array of Objects which share the super type `Class`.

In Java, everything is an `Object`.  This means that if you want to have in-code awareness of class types, you need to create an `Object` which can encapsulate the details of the class.  Java calls this `Object` a `Class`.

Note the capitalization and be aware that since `Class` is an `Object`, you can call all `Object` methods on class, like `x.getClass()`, `x.wait()`, and `x.hashcode()`.

```
Class[] items = { String.class, Integer.class };
```

means create an array called items which contains `Class` objects.  Initialize the array with the `Object`s representing the class of `String` and the class of `Integer`.

Since `Class` objects represent class types, often the two are used interchangeably in informal speech.

Comment: erh.. In java not everything is an object.

Comment: @Oscar, ok, yes there's primitives.  But if you dig into the implementation of the JVM, you'll find that Interfaces are implemented as classes and handled like objects.

Answer (score 1):

That's an array of the type `Class`

The

```
new Class[] {...}
```

Creates and array of type `Class` whose contents are listed inside.

In general

*Type*[]  means, an "array of..." just like you thought.

It turns out the type here is `Class` which in Java is a representation of a running class or interface.

Probably you shouldn't go for advanced features like reflection without knowing first the basics.

Comment: It was more the syntax of the new Blah[] { a, b, c} that confused me.  I wasn't quite sure what was going on there.  I'm pretty familiar with JVM, classloaders, bytecode, reflection etc.  Just a n00b syntax question mainly.

Comment: @nazbot I'm glad to hear that. I thought it was your first look into the language and definitely reflection is not a good place to start.

Comment: That's true.  Appreciate the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is actually a class named, uhmm.. Class.

   Instances of the class Class represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application.
2. `new Class[]` works. It initializes an array of Class references. But, as usual with object arrays, the references are null.
3. Class `Class` does not have a public constructor. So you can not say `new Class()`

Answer (score 0):

`Class` is a java class that represents ... a class and related metadata. so `Class[]` is an array of `Class` objects.

Each class in java has a static member variable named class of type Class and here what you're doing is

1. creating a Class[] containing two
   members each of which is an object of
   type Class and specifically the Class
   representing java.lang.String
2. looking up via reflection the
   reference to the constructor in the
   class TwoString that takes two
   java.lang.String objects =>
   TwoString(String, String)
3. creating an object array to feed to
   the constructor with the values "a"
   and "b"
4. finally you're creating an instance
   of TwoString ts by invoking the
   constructor you looked up in (b) and
   args you initialized in (c)

This is equivalent to:

```
TwoString ts = new TwoString("a","b");
```

but the way you've posted is using Reflection/Introspection.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the `Class[]` in the example is mimicking the constructor in that TwoString class. To me it would have been clearer if they would have used two different types. So if the TwoString class looked like this:

```
public class TwoString {

    private String m_s1;
    private Integer m_s2;
    public TwoString(String s1, Integer s2) {
        m_s1 = s1;
        m_s2 = s2;
    }


}
```

The class name would not make since anymore, but I think that is easy to fix. The rest of the code example would become:

```
Class[] types = new Class[] { String.class, Integer.class };
Constructor cons = TwoString.class.getConstructor(types);
Object[] args = new Object[] { "a", 1 };
TwoString ts = (TwoString)cons.newInstance(args);
```

So the class array is to set up the constructor to use. The steps line by line are:

1. The class array sets up what constructor to use.
2. Then you find the constructor.
3. The you set up what values to pass into the constuctor.
4. Then you call the constructor to create the instance.